# Group by aggregate dynamic column name matching

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

Is it possible to `group_by` using regex match on column names using dplyr?

```
library(dplyr) # dplyr_0.5.0; R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)

# dummy data
set.seed(1)
df1 <-  sample_n(iris, 20) %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = round(Sepal.Length),
         Sepal.Width = round(Sepal.Width))
```

Group by *static* version (looks/works fine, imagine if we have 10-20 columns):

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>% 
  summarise(mySum = sum(Petal.Length))
```

Group by *dynamic* - "ugly" version:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by_(.dots = colnames(df1)[ grepl("^Sepal", colnames(df1))]) %>% 
  summarise(mySum = sum(Petal.Length))
```

Ideally, something like this (doesn't work, as `starts_with` returns indices):

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(starts_with("Sepal")) %>% 
  summarise(mySum = sum(Petal.Length))
```

> ```
> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
>    wrong result size (0), expected 20 or 1
> ```

Expected output:

```
# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# Groups: Sepal.Length [?]
# 
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width mySum
#          <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
# 1            4           3   1.4
# 2            5           3  10.9
# 3            6           2   4.0
# 4            6           3  43.7
# 5            7           3  15.7
# 6            8           4   6.4
```

---

**Note:** sounds very much like a duplicated post, kindly link the relevant posts if any.

Comment: `df1 %>% group_by_(.dots = grep("^Sepal", names(.), value = TRUE))`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus yes, a little bit prettier version of my ugly version.

Comment: I think the reason it doesn't work with `starts_with` is because `group_by` requires character input whereas `starts_with` returns indices of columns

Comment: @docendodiscimus yes, it is supposed to work with `select` which accepts column indices, would be nice to have similar for `group_by`, hoping it already exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<del>This feature will be implemented in future release</del>, reference [GitHub issue #2619](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2619):

Solution would be to use `group_by_at` function:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by_at(vars(starts_with("Sepal"))) %>% 
  summarise(mySum = sum(Petal.Length))
```

---

**Edit:** This is now implemented in **dplyr_0.7.1**

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to keep it with `dplyr` functions, you can try:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by_(.dots = df1 %>% select(contains("Sepal")) %>% colnames()) %>%
  summarise(mySum = sum(Petal.Length))
```

though it's not necessarily much prettier, but it gets rid of the regex

Comment: Ouch, this looks worse than my version. Intention is not to get rid of regex, but finding out if there is a "proper" dplyr way of doing this.

Comment: yeah. I feel the pain. we should not need to nest it in such a way to begin with.