# group_by variables which meet a certain condition in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to summarize the variables in the data frame below that begin with `var_` by all other variables in the data set

```
dta <- data.frame(cbind(matrix(sample(1:10, 3000, replace = T), 
                           nrow = 100, 
                           ncol = 30),
                    matrix(rnorm(7000), 
                           nrow = 100, 
                           ncol = 70)))

names(dta) <- c(paste0('group_', 1:30), paste0('var_', 1:70))
```

I was thinking something along the lines of this may work, but I haven't had any success

```
dta %>% group_by(!contains('var')) %>% summarize_all(mean)
```

In my real dataset, the `group_` variables above all have different names, but I'd essentially like to group by everything which is not one of the variables to be summarized.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229133/

Comment: Also consider reshaping your data to long format which seems more sensible

Comment: The development version of dplyr has a `group_by_at` function for this sort of situation.  An example on github [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2619)